# How to handle errors in Angular 5 APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular

I load some data in the `APP_INITIALIZER` that the app must have to run.  I want to know if there is any way to handle errors in the `APP_INITIALIZER` such that when the app finally starts up I can display an error to the user.  In my `APP_INITIALIZER` I catch all errors so the promises returned are valid and the app starts up but I don't know how to handle the error conditions that may be encountered in the `APP_INITIALIZER`.  If there is a better app startup event that could be used for this I would but unlike AngularJs' abstract route capability it seems that `APP_INITIALIZER` is the only way get data on app start.

Comment: You could always set any errors into an Observable (state) and display a message in components to that effect.

Comment: @Brandon Except there are no services or any app functionality available in the initializer.

Comment: An initializer can contain any code you want. I recently completed a project that has shared metadata across the entire application that is loaded from an API endpoint. When the `APP_INITIALIZER` is provided, I supply the injected service as a dependency.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow You can inject any services you need into `APP_INITIALIZER`. Just add them to the `deps` property of the provider in the module. That way, you can have that service available app-wide and know of the error state.